# How can I write to check a URL?

Tags: java, url

A friend of mine requested to write a simple code to check whether a URL ends with asp or not. I am thinking about accepting the URL as string and checking the last tree letters if it's as or not. I just want to check is there any ways to  write this code. (of course there are plenty of ways but it need to be simple)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you concerned with querystring variables?  eg: ../index.asp?article=1455&category=32

Comment: I guess. How can I find a solution for that kind of input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to use the [`String.endsWith()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
if (s.endsWith("asp")) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

If you really want to do this properly, you can parse the string as a real [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and extract the path using `getPath()`.

```
URL url = new URL(s);
String path = url.getPath();
if (path.endsWith("asp")) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Im going to write the output yes or no into a text file. However I cannot think how to build it yet. Also what if the string ends with index.asp?article=123. As Ken mentioned.

Comment: @the magnificent: Answer updated to handle things like `index.asp?article=123`. As for writing to a file, use a FileWriter or just redirect the output of your program.

Comment: Thanks Adam.. This looks more logical

Answer (score 4):

```
String url = ... 
if(url.endsWith(".asp")){
    // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
.*\.asp(x){0,1}(\?){0,1}.*
```

This will handle these cases:

- http://example.com/index.asp
- http://example.com/index.asp?id=564
- http://example.com/index.aspx
- http://example.com/index.aspx?id=564&id2=333

Answer (score 0):

A regex would be a solution though I find them extremely ugly in Java.

```
String url = ....
if (Pattern.compile("\.asp[^\.]*\z").matcher(url).matches()){
  //do your thing
}
```

Yuk indeed. And i'm not sure if I got the regex right